# malformed utf-8 data cryptoJS

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, google-cloud-functions, cryptojs

I am trying to create a JSON object, encrypt it using AES, and then send the data, however I am getting an error when I decrypt it.
The following code works perfectly, it encrypts, and decrypts the needed info.

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(token), 'AGsrv54SDG2DA');
console.log("token is :" + encrypted.toString());
//U2FsdGVkX19QYpU9XWLESHzRB7uvFMtc1J/pCbJjXelTHyeEmU4LCsIMpYZGl9Bs157sX2f47fGeAW4EIaCGiPATxX2PdpZ YMdvPKDIaPYPnmlEJa9yZWyfXf80FNbkRM9Jo9M8GrMiAg8baK6S8GH7GdwxeZEVVkLJpFpgFBUPS3xn2sy/bMHWvOK0lPT0

var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted.toString(), 'AGsrv54SDG2DA');
console.log('BYTES BEFORE:' + bytes);
//bytes : 7b2254797065223a22415554485f434f4445222c22554944223a226e6866476a424c30306c5866735763783332333275587171306c6932222c22434944223a22486f6d655370616365434944222c2245584154223a22546875204d617920333120323031382031373a32333a323920474d542b30303030202855544329227d
var decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
console.log("auth token UID for test is " + decryptedData.UID); //this works 100%

return {token : encrypted.toString()};
```

the `return` statement returns the stringed version of the encrypted data back to my web page. the token is then sent back to another cloud function which attempts to decrypt it as following:

```
inToken = req.body.code;
console.log("auth token given:" + inToken);
//U2FsdGVkX19QYpU9XWLESHzRB7uvFMtc1J/pCbJjXelTHyeEmU4LCsIMpYZGl9Bs157sX2f47fGeAW4EIaCGiPATxX2PdpZ YMdvPKDIaPYPnmlEJa9yZWyfXf80FNbkRM9Jo9M8GrMiAg8baK6S8GH7GdwxeZEVVkLJpFpgFBUPS3xn2sy/bMHWvOK0lPT0

var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(inToken, 'AGsrv54SDG2DA');
console.log('BYTES AFTER:' + bytes);
//7b2254797065223a22415554485f434f4445222c22554944223a226e6866476a424c30306c5866735763783332333275587171306c6932222c22434944223a22486f6d655370616365434944222c2245584154223a22546875204d617920333120323031382031373a32333a323920474d542b30303030202855544329227d
var jsonToken = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

however this throws 
`Error: Malformed UTF-8 data at Object.stringify`

Comment: Exactly which line/function throws that error?  What exactly is the contents of `req.body.code` and `bytes`?

Comment: @DougStevenson the last line of code.and req.body.code is the incoming request body which holds the value of the token which i returned - `encrypted.toString()`

Comment: And the answers to my other question?

Comment: @DougStevenson `bytes` is the CryptoJS decrypted object of the token. we need this before we can rebuild the json object

Comment: Still from my first comment: What exactly is the value of `req.body.code`?

Comment: @DougStevenson , perhaps my comment was a bit ambiguous, `req.body.code` is the value of the token which i returned in the first block of code. it is `encrypted.toString()`

Comment: Have you verified that the actual values of these things are exactly what you think they are by logging them to the console?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, please see the edit, i have included my full code. the logs are all the same.

Comment: You still haven't included the actual values.  There's no way we can try this for ourselves without the actual data being worked on.

Comment: @DougStevenson i added the actual logged values now

Comment: In what google-cloud product are you deploying your app?

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez this is in firebase cloud functions. which processes the data for the website